# While loop doesn't exit after writing to file in C

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I'm sending a file from the client to the server. I take an input from the client, and in this case its for file transfer and after completion the client is supposed to reprompt for a new command. This is how I send a file:

Client (sends):

```
            size_t bytes_read = 0;
            ssize_t bytes_written = 0;
            
            
            while((bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp)) > 0){ 
            
                if ((bytes_written = write(sd, buf, bytes_read)) < 0){
                    printf("Error sending client file.\n");
                }
            
            }
            
            printf("bytes written: %ld\n", bytes_written);
            fclose(fp);
            }
```

Server (receives):

```
             while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0){ 
                    
                printf("The contents: %s", buf);
                fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, fp);
                printf("Done writing\n");
                
                }
                printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");
                fclose(fp);
```

The problem I'm having, is that the print statement `printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");` is never executed which is the last statement I print before this IF statement carrying all the operations is closed. And I'm unable to enter new commands from the client because I assume its stuck in this while loop. Only when I force stop the server program, that print line is reached and then the program exits. The strange thing, is that after I force stop it I can see that the file I transferred has actually been transferred correctly. But why wont it leave this while loop?

Comment: Are you using *blocking* sockets? Then `read` will block (not return) until it have received something, the connection was closed, or there is an error. You might want to do some research about non-blocking sockets and how to use them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay, i will try that and yeah I'm using blocking sockets.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the sender not closing the socket, `sd` (you don't show a `close(sd)`), so the receiver does not get an EOF indication (reported as zero bytes read).  If you want to keep the socket open (not wholly unreasonable), then you need to establish a protocol such that you send the length of the file in a 4-byte (or maybe 8-byte) message before you send the contents, and the receiver gets told how many bytes to expect and knows to stop when it has received that many bytes (it has to keep a count).  You might have to worry about endianness in client and server too.

Answer (score 1):

(need formatting on a comment, so temporary CW answer)

> Only when I force stop the server program, that print line is reached and then the program exits.

(He presses ^Z shoving it into the background.)

The problem isn't in the posted code. Demonstration: add the following lines after `printf`:

```
fflush(stdout);
_exit(0);
```

Poof, process exits.

Comment: I only force stop it because it doesnt leave the while loop, and I just wanted to see what happens. And what happens is that the print statement is executed and it exits the program afterwards. I just tried fflush and it didnt work :( Basically the last print statement my server executes without me force stopping, is `printf("Done writing\n");`

Comment: I can only think that somehow my while loop is always `>0` or something? But if i make it `==0` it will ignore errors so im not sure what to do

Comment: @DarrenFernando: How exactly do you force stop it?

Comment: I just press CTRL-Z on my server terminal

Comment: @DarrenFernando: CTRL-Z is normally EOF (WIndows) or suspend to background (Linux). What did you DO?

Comment: @DarrenFernando: Unless you've seriously messed with something, ^Z is going to immediately suspend the process and make the shell active again with no chance to output anything; however as the process is still running in the background. I have found with most compilers, the next compile errors out with ETXTBUSY.

Comment: When I try to recompile my server, it doesnt let me because as you said its running in the background. So I kill its PID and recompile it again.

Comment: Its rather frustrating because it took me a while to get this file transfer down, and now that its actually transferring the entire file its not leaving this while loop..