# File transfer completes, but program doesn't receive end of file condition to stop writing in C

Tags: c, sockets, file-transfer, fwrite, fread

When sending my file from the client to the server, the receiving while loop I have does not stop, so I have to use CTRL-Z on linux to get out of the program and move it to the background, and then kill its process id. The thing is, after I exit that way and check my folder, I can see that the document has succesffully transferred and every byte was transferred succesfully. But the while loop never breaks, and I know this because the print statement after my while loop on server (receiving side) is never printed out.

I've tried using non-blocking sockets. I don't know what the problem could be because the file is sent successfully, but the server is still in the while loop trying to write to file.

Client (sends):

```
        else if(strcmp(shortCommand, "put") == 0){
            
            
            char *tmp = buf + 4;
            char filename[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
            int x;
            strcpy(filename, "filename ");
            strcat(filename, tmp);
            FILE *fp;
            printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
            fp = fopen(tmp, "rb");
            if(fp == NULL){
                
                printf("ERROR: Requested file does not exist.\n");
                
            }
            else{
            printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((x = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0){     //sending the file name to the client first
                printf("Error sending client's filename.\n");
            }
            
            printf("Client sending file...\n");
            size_t bytes_read = 0;
            ssize_t bytes_written = 0;
            
            
            while((bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp)) > 0){ //sending the file
            
                if ((bytes_written = write(sd, buf, bytes_read)) < 0){
                    printf("Error sending client file.\n");
                }
            
            }
            printf("bytes written: %ld\n", bytes_written);
            fclose(fp);
            }   
    }
```

Server(receives):

```
if(strcmp(shortCommand, "put") == 0){
                char *tmp = buf + 4;
                char filename2[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
                ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
                size_t bytes_written = 0;
                FILE *fp;
                strcpy(filename2, tmp);
                printf("Server receiving file name...\n");
                //first 'read' receives the file name, which happens before this IF
                fp = fopen(filename2, "wb");
                if(fp == NULL){
                    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                printf("Server receiving file...\n");
                while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0){ //second read now retrieving the file
                    
                    fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, fp);

                }
                printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");
                fclose(fp);
    }
```

In essence, the last print statement `printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");`is never executed

Comment: You never seem to close the socket connection. which means `read` will block (as I mentioned in [your previous almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673931/while-loop-doesnt-exit-after-writing-to-file-in-c)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But I don't wish to close the connection, I only close the connection when the client enters the word 'quit'. If he doesn't enter quit, I keep entering commands to do stuff, the server does its part and gets back to the client and so on and so forth until I type in 'quit', and it works for my other commands. So how would I make it the same way for this one without having to close the socket explicitly, or do I simply have to close it?

Comment: Then you need some way to say "end of file". For example you could send the size of the file first, so you know *exactly* how much to receive, and can simply stop receiving at that point.

Comment: Oh okay, I will try implementing that. Thank you

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've implemented it, and Im having the exact same issue, would you mind looking at it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675323/program-stuck-writing-contents-to-the-file-in-c?noredirect=1#comment114354702_64675323