# Program stuck writing contents to the file in C

Tags: c, file, file-transfer, fwrite, fread

I'm sending a file from the client to the server.

- Client sends filename
- Server receives filename
- Client sends file size
- Server receives file size
- Client sends file contents
- Server receives file contents

When I print out the file size that I sent, it is the exact number of bytes as the file I wish to send so that's fine. The issue is that the server (receives) doesn't seem to exit the while loop when writing to the new file. I know this because the final print statement printf("The server has received the requested document\n"); is never reached and it just hangs. What could be causing this?

Client snippet (sends):

```
 else if(strcmp(shortCommand, "put") == 0){
            
            
            char *tmp = buf + 4;
            char filename[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
        size_t size, bytes_read, bytes_written;
        int x;

            strcpy(filename, "filename ");
            strcat(filename, tmp);
            FILE *fp;
            printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
            fp = fopen(tmp, "rb");
            if(fp == NULL){
                
                printf("ERROR: Requested file does not exist.\n");
                
            }
            else{
            printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((x = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0){     //sending the file name to the client first
                printf("Error sending client's filename.\n");
            }

            printf("Client sending file...\n");
            
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
            size = ftell(fp);
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            printf("Sending file size\n");
            
            if((write(sd, &size, sizeof(size))) < 0){ //sending filesize
                printf("error sending file size\n");
            }
            
            printf("Sending file\n");
            while((bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp)) > 0){ //sending file contents
            
                if ((bytes_written = write(sd, buf, bytes_read)) < 0){
                    printf("Error sending client file.\n");
                }
            
            }
            printf("bytes written: %ld\n", bytes_written);
            fclose(fp);
            }   
    }
```

Server snippet (receives):

```
if(strcmp(shortCommand, "put") == 0){
                char *tmp = buf + 4;
                char filename2[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
                size_t  filesize;
                size_t total_bytes_read = 0;
                ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
                size_t error;
                FILE *fp;
                strcpy(filename2, tmp);
                printf("Server receiving file name...\n"); //filename is received on the first read before this IF
                fp = fopen(filename2, "wb");
                if(fp == NULL){
                    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                
                printf("Server receiving file size...\n");
                
                if((error = read(sd, &filesize, sizeof(filesize))) < 0){ //receiving file size
                    perror("Error reading filesize\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                
                printf("Filesize is: %ld \n", filesize);
                
                while(total_bytes_read < filesize){
                    while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0){ //receving file contents and writing to file
                        fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, fp);
                        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
                    if(ferror(fp)){
                        perror("error");
                        fclose(fp);
                    }
                    }
                }
                printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");
                fflush(stdout);
                fclose(fp);
    }
```

After I exit the program by force, I can actually see that the file has been copied. Just doesn't exit that while loop to let me go back to the client.

Comment: You could check the value of bytes_read at every iteration of the loop

Comment: if read() function return -1 or 0 at any time , your program might never exit  this loop                 while(total_bytes_read < filesize)

Comment: @Arthur so what happens is for a file with 6000+ bytes, each iteration is reading 256 bytes until the last iteration reading whatever number of bytes is remaining, and then it hangs again. 256 is the size I have assigned to buf like `char buf[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE]` where `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE` is 256

Comment: @Arthur But my while loop is like  `while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)`, so it should stop when 0 or -1 is returned right?

Comment: i am talking about the orther loop : " while(total_bytes_read < filesize) " ... read() return is added to total_bytes_read but if it's -1 or 0 : total_bytes_read willl never be over filesize.... when read() return 0 it loops forever

Comment: you could try taking out the outer loop :" while(total_bytes_read < filesize) "

Comment: Please add complete code instead of incomplete fragments.

Comment: @Arhurr I have resolved the issue, and explained it in a comment in the answer down below, for anyone else wondering. Thanks for your help

Comment: regarding: `printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((x = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0){`   the contents of array `buf[]` has not been set.  Also the array `filename[]` has been set.   Suggest: `printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((x = write(sd, filename, strlen( filename ))) < 0) {`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler doesn't care) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: regarding: `size_t size, bytes_read, bytes_written;` and `size = ftell(fp);`  The function: `ftell()` can return -1, but `size_t` is unsigned.  Strongly suggest  1) remove `size` from the declaration and use: `long size = ftell( fp );`

Comment: regarding code blocks like: `if ((x = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0){     //sending the file name to the client first
                printf("Error sending client's filename.\n");
            }`  the code must NOT continue (as if the call to write() was successful.  Rather, much better to call `fclose()` for the open file and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` to exit the program.  Also, error messages should be output to `stderr`. not `stdout`.  Best to also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  Suggest calling `perror()` for this purpose.

Comment: regarding: `if ((x = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0)`  This fails to account for the server 'hanging up' ( which would cause the `write()` to return 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time for some basic debugging. I'd suggest changing your read loop to something like this:

```c
while (total_bytes_read < filesize) {
    printf("DEBUG A: total=%zu, size=%zu\n", total_bytes_read, filesize);
    while ((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
        printf("DEBUG B: read=%zd\n", bytes_read);
        fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, fp);
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
        printf("DEBUG C: total=%zu\n", total_bytes_read);
        if (ferror(fp))
            printf("DEBUG D\n");
            perror("error");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        printf("DEBUG E\n");
    }
    printf("DEBUG F\n");
}
printf("DEBUG G\n");
```

Then run it, piping the output through `less` or some other pager, it should then hopefully become clearer what's actually happening.

Feel free to post the output of this modified code (in a comment, or in the actual question), we'll no doubt be able to help with the analysis.

Comment: That was actually very helpful, thank you. I dont know how to use 'less' or even know what pagers are, I apologize. But with this debugging, for 'DEBUG C' I can see that the loop stops when all bytes are read into total_bytes. So every byte has been written properly. But after that, it just hangs

Comment: @DarrenFernando: so you have *no* more output after the final C? I suggest you add a few more as per my update then try again, and *post* the output you get.

Comment: Hey Pax, so I've figured out what to do for anyone else wondering as well. So I deleted the initial while loop `while (total_bytes_read < filesize)` and instead, inside the next while loop I added the condition `if(total_bytes_read == filesize)` then` break`, so that the loop exits once all bytes are written, and it works. Your debugging helped me heaps, thank you!